# Group set of objects based on a string value and edit

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string

I have a array of objects like this

```
const resultSet = [
    {
        start: 'A',
        end: 'B',
        val: 1

    },
    {
        start: 'B',
        end: 'C',
        val: 3
    },
    {
        start: 'B',
        end: 'D',
        val: 1

    },
    {
        start: 'B',
        end: 'A',
        val: 4
    },
    {
        start: 'C',
        end: 'B',
        val: 1
    }
]
```

For the objects which have the same start and end (also in reverse order), the val should be updated with the maximum value among val.
For instance, the first object and the fourth object in the array should have the same val as 4 since it is the **max(1,4)**.

The final result should look like this

```
const finalSet = [
    {
        start: 'A',
        end: 'B',
        val: 4

    },
    {
        start: 'B',
        end: 'C',
        val: 3
    },
    {
        start: 'B',
        end: 'D',
        val: 1

    },
    {
        start: 'B',
        end: 'A',
        val: 4
    },
    {
        start: 'C',
        end: 'B',
        val: 3
    }
]
```

I started with the following

```
const strArray = resultSet.map(element => {
    return {
        str: [element.start, element.end].sort().join(''),
        val: element.val
    }
})

console.log(strArray)
```

I did end up with a array of objects

```
[
  { str: 'AB', val: 1 },
  { str: 'BC', val: 3 },
  { str: 'BD', val: 1 },
  { str: 'AB', val: 4 },
  { str: 'BC', val: 1 }
]
```

My idea is to somehow group this result based on the value of str and use Max function on the group to update val to the max value. Is there a efficient way to do this?

In case there is a better approach than what I was trying, please let me know too.

Comment: Can you please clarify which final result you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution will be to iterate over the array, find all matching entries, map them to values and find max. Then just update val property.

```js
   const list = [
     {
       start: 'A',
       end: 'B',
       val: 1
     },
     {
       start: 'B',
       end: 'C',
       val: 3
     },
     {
       start: 'B',
       end: 'D',
       val: 1

     },
     {
       start: 'B',
       end: 'A',
       val: 4
     },
     {
       start: 'C',
       end: 'B',
       val: 1
     }
  ]

list.forEach(o1 => {
    const arr = list.filter( o2 => (o2.start === o1.start && o1.end === o2.end) || (o2.start === o1.end && o2.end === o1.start) )
                    .map(o2 => o2.val);
    o1.val = Math.max(...arr);
});
            
console.log(list);
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if it were a runnable snippet

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with normalized key and max value and map the data with max values.

```js
const
    getKey = ({ start, end }) => [start, end].sort().join('|'),
    data = [{ start: 'A', end: 'B', val: 1  }, { start: 'B', end: 'C', val: 3 }, { start: 'B', end: 'D', val: 1 }, { start: 'B', end: 'A', val: 4 }, { start: 'C', end: 'B', val: 1 }],
    max = data.reduce((m, o) => {
        const key = getKey(o);
        if (!(key in m) || m[key] < o.val) m[key] = o.val;
        return m;
    }, {}),
    result = data.map(o => ({ ...o, val: max[getKey(o)] }));

console.log(result);
console.log(max);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first make an object with all the highest values. Afterwards loop over your array and apply the correct values.

```js
const finalSet = [
    { start: 'A', end: 'B', val: 4 },
    { start: 'B', end: 'C', val: 3 },
    { start: 'B', end: 'D', val: 1 },
    { start: 'B', end: 'A', val: 4 },
    { start: 'C', end: 'B', val: 3 }
];

/**
 * Get key based on `start` and `end` props.
 */
const getKey = obj => [obj.start, obj.end].sort().join(''); // Might be better to use `localeCompare` for sorting strings.

/**
 * Get highest value based on key.
 */
const highestValues = finalSet.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const key = getKey(obj);
  acc[key] ??= 0;
  
  if(obj.val > acc[key]) {
    acc[key] = obj.val;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

/**
 * Update initial values with highest value.
 */
const result = finalSet.map(obj => {
  const key = getKey(obj);
  obj.val = highestValues[key];
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using `Object.values` and `Array.reduce`

```js
const  data = [{ start: 'A', end: 'B', val: 1  }, { start: 'B', end: 'C', val: 3 }, { start: 'B', end: 'D', val: 1 }, { start: 'B', end: 'A', val: 4 }, { start: 'C', end: 'B', val: 1 }];

const calculateResult = data => Object.values(data.reduce((res, el) => {
  const [start, end] = [el.start, el.end].sort()
  const key = [start, end].join('')
  const val = res[key] ? Math.max(res[key].val, el.val): el.val
 return {
   ...res,
   [key]: {
    start,
    end,
    val
 }
 }
}, {}))

console.log(calculateResult(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```